# Injecting Environment Variable into Groovy / Spring

Tags: spring, groovy

I have a groovy class that uses spring injection to get a hostname (previously defined in *application.properties*). It works fine, the code looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
... ...
    @Value('${mycontext.var1}')
    private String serverHost
```

Now, instead of using *application.properties*, I'd like to inject from an environment variable named *SERVER_HOSTNAME*. I tried the following, but it does **not** work.

```
@Value('${System.getenv("SERVER_HOSTNAME")}')
private String serverHost
```

Comment: In my Spring projects, `@Value("${SERVER_HOSTNAME}")` works, because of https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html -- but I'm not making it an answer because I've not tried in Groovy, and it may be that Spring Boot does extra magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the following piece of code should work:

```
@Value("#{environment.SERVER_HOSTNAME}")
private String serverHost
```